# Waste or Wastes

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

In the sentence below, is "waste" grammatically appropriate because "Category A" is a group of medical waste?

"**What treatment methods are used for Ebola or other Category A medical wastes?**"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94937/discussion-on-question-by-bretta-waste-or-wastes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What treatment methods are used for Ebola **or** other Category A medical waste?"

The use of the conjunction OR means you would use a singular noun, regardless of any other possibilities, a**s there is only one category here with an or**.

- French bread
- sliced bread

*Do you want to serve French ***or*** sliced bread at the dinner?*

Breads would not work here. [Yeah, I know you could, if you really wanted to, come up with a plural if there were different kinds of French bread and sliced bread but here they are categories of bread, so please do not.]

Medical waste of the same category (infectious waste) would not take an s.

[Sorry, no reference as this question should probably be on ELL anyway.]

Comment: You're choosing a noun with a different distribution. Why not '"What treatment methods are used for Ebola or other Category A medical wastes?"  to mean "What treatment methods are used for Ebola or the wastes associated with other Category A pathogens?" The 'or' simply indicates that the questioner is asking for an answer referencing one of the pathogens. 'Household waste' has a very different distribution. Analogies using other nouns / attributed nouns don't work here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because generally medical waste is singular especially when an or conjunction is used for a single category.  Major **or** minor waste. My answer coheres with the OP's question and you are mucking it and me around.

Comment: There are 238 000 Google Hits for "medical wastes", some from reference works, some from prestigious bodies such as [EPA](https://www.epa.gov/rcra/medical-waste). / Ebola and Marburg wastes can be seen as _different_ categories. It depends what you're emphasising.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "medical and other waste": Google: About 112,000 results (0.25 seconds)||"medical and other waste**s**: Google: About 36,200 results (0.45 seconds)||and the plural wastes, for medical and other wastes: 7 hits. My main point was about the conjunction **or** and the single usage as waste in the OP's question refers to a single type: infectious waste or health care waste.